# Change color on widget tap flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement logic, where animated circle will change its color on tap.

The statement which I use looks following way:

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      var circlePainter = CirclePainter(
      _controller,
      color: Colors.red,
      onTap: ()  => setState(() {
      // ignore: unnecessary_statements
      _controller;
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 16, 144, 31);
      }),
      );
```

And color still remains the same

full snippet

```
    class RipplesAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
    const RipplesAnimation({
    required Key key, 
    this.size = 80.0, 
    this.color = Colors.red,
    onPressed, 

    }) : super(key: key);
    final double size;
    final Color color;

    @override
   _RipplesAnimationState createState() => 
   _RipplesAnimationState();
 
   }
```

Comment: `color: Colors.red,` can you include full sample snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a variable which you set to the specific color.

```
Color selectedColor = Colors.red;
```

Set this to yourCirclePainter

```
color: selectedColor,
```

Inside your onTap you call setState and change it to your next color:

```
onTap: ()  => setState(() {
      color = Color.fromARGB(255, 16, 144, 31);
      });
```

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. ' Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var circlePainter = CirclePainter(
      _controller,
      color: selectedColor,
      onTap: ()  => setState(() {
      color =  Color.fromARGB(255, 16, 144, 31); 
      }),
      );'  The error says Undefined name 'color'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name. Even though I defined it inside CirclePaint and inside state I added variable class _RipplesAnimationState extends State<RipplesAnimation> 
with TickerProviderStateMixin {
 
 Color selectedColor = Colors.red;

Comment: You have to assign to selectedColor, not color.